# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "android.net.wifi.WifiNetworkSuggestion$Builder" on path: DexPathList

Tags: android, kotlin, wifi

I was developing an app, which their main goal is to access the device WiFi, and make some configuration.

I get into a problem which look like to be related which a API level compatibility with my device (run on API 27).

The class which cause the exception is "WifiNetworkSuggestion", which is added on API 29, and bring me the following error:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Landroid/net/wifi/WifiNetworkSuggestion$Builder;
at es.paytef.wificepsamanager.SharedViewModel.connectUsingNetworkSuggestion(SharedViewModel.kt:95)
at es.paytef.wificepsamanager.SharedViewModel.access$connectUsingNetworkSuggestion(SharedViewModel.kt:30) at es.paytef.wificepsamanager.SharedViewModel$launchWifiConfiguration$1.invokeSuspend(SharedViewModel.kt:86) at kotlin.coroutines.jvm.internal.BaseContinuationImpl.resumeWith(ContinuationImpl.kt:33)
at kotlinx.coroutines.DispatchedTask.run(DispatchedTask.kt:106)
at kotlinx.coroutines.internal.LimitedDispatcher.run(LimitedDispatcher.kt:42)
at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.TaskImpl.run(Tasks.kt:95)
at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler.runSafely(CoroutineScheduler.kt:570)
at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler$Worker.executeTask(CoroutineScheduler.kt:750)
at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler$Worker.runWorker(CoroutineScheduler.kt:677)
at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler$Worker.run(CoroutineScheduler.kt:664)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "android.net.wifi.WifiNetworkSuggestion$Builder" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/es.paytef.wificepsamanager-DxLMs6WviARM6K0hEd8RSw==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/es.paytef.wificepsamanager-DxLMs6WviARM6K0hEd8RSw==/lib/arm, /data/resource/lib, /system/lib, /vendor/lib]]
```

Regarding my code, is the following:

MainActivity.kt

```
@RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.S)
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setUI()
        processWifiConfiguration(applicationContext)
    }

    @RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.S)
    private fun processWifiConfiguration(context: Context) {
        
        val wifiConfig = WifiEnterpriseConfig()
        wifiConfig.eapMethod = WifiEnterpriseConfig.Eap.PEAP
        wifiConfig.phase2Method = Phase2.MSCHAPV2
        wifiConfig.caCertificate = null
        wifiConfig.anonymousIdentity = null
        wifiConfig.identity = BuildConfig.WIFI_USER
        wifiConfig.password = BuildConfig.WIFI_PASS


        val info = WifiInfo(
            security =  WifiEnterpriseConfig.Eap.TLS,
            eapMethod = wifiConfig.eapMethod,
            phase2Auth = wifiConfig.phase2Method,
            caCertificate = wifiConfig.caCertificate,
            anonymousIdentity = wifiConfig.anonymousIdentity,
            identity = wifiConfig.identity,
            password = wifiConfig.password,
            ssid = BuildConfig.WIFI_SSID
        )
        viewModel.launchWifiConfiguration(context = context, info = info, config = wifiConfig)
    }
```

SharedViewModel.kt

```
@HiltViewModel
class SharedViewModel @Inject constructor(@ApplicationContext context: Context): ViewModel() {

    private val wifiManager: WifiManager = context.applicationContext.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE) as WifiManager
    private var lastSuggestedNetwork: WifiNetworkSuggestion? = null

    private val _isLoading: MutableStateFlow<Boolean> = MutableStateFlow(false)
    val isLoading:StateFlow<Boolean> = _isLoading.asStateFlow()
    @RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.Q)
    fun launchWifiConfiguration(context:Context, info: WifiInfo, config:WifiEnterpriseConfig){
        viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
            _isLoading.emit(true)
            if(!wifiManager.isWifiEnabled){
                wifiManager.isWifiEnabled = true
            }
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.S) {
                wifiManager.callerConfiguredNetworks.map {
                    it.enterpriseConfig.identity = info.identity
                    it.enterpriseConfig.password = info.password
                    it.enterpriseConfig.eapMethod = info.eapMethod
                    it.enterpriseConfig.caCertificate = info.caCertificate
                    it.enterpriseConfig.anonymousIdentity = info.anonymousIdentity
                    it.enterpriseConfig.phase2Method = info.phase2Auth
                    it.setSecurityParams(info.security)
                    Log.d("es.paytef", "Settea los params del wifi en S")
                    //TODO: call the receiver
                    connectUsingNetworkSuggestion(context, ssid = info.ssid.toString(), password = info.password.toString())
                    _isLoading.emit(false)
                }
            }else{
                if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(
                        context,
                        Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION
                    ) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
                ) {
                    // TODO: Consider calling
                    //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
                    // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
                    //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
                    //                                          int[] grantResults)
                    // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
                    // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
                    return@launch
                }
                wifiManager.configuredNetworks.map {
                    it.enterpriseConfig.identity = info.identity
                    it.enterpriseConfig.password = info.password
                    it.enterpriseConfig.eapMethod = info.eapMethod
                    it.enterpriseConfig.caCertificate = info.caCertificate
                    it.enterpriseConfig.anonymousIdentity = info.anonymousIdentity
                    it.enterpriseConfig.phase2Method = info.phase2Auth
                    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.R) {
                        it.setSecurityParams(info.security)
                    }
                    Log.d("es.paytef", "Settea los params del wifi")
                    //TODO: call the receiver
                    connectUsingNetworkSuggestion(context, ssid = info.ssid.toString(), password = info.password.toString())
                    _isLoading.emit(false)
                }
            }
        }
    }
    //TODO: Check the min version: Current device version is 27, and min is 29.
    @RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.Q)
    private fun connectUsingNetworkSuggestion(context: Context, ssid: String, password: String) {
        val wifiNetworkSuggestion = WifiNetworkSuggestion.Builder()
            .setSsid(ssid)
            .setWpa2Passphrase(password)
            .build()
        val intentFilter =
            IntentFilter(WifiManager.ACTION_WIFI_NETWORK_SUGGESTION_POST_CONNECTION);

        val broadcastReceiver = object : BroadcastReceiver() {
            override fun onReceive(context: Context, intent: Intent) {
                if (!intent.action.equals(WifiManager.ACTION_WIFI_NETWORK_SUGGESTION_POST_CONNECTION)) {
                    return
                }
                Log.d("es.paytef", "Connection Suggestion Succeeded")
            }
        }


        registerReceiver(context,broadcastReceiver, intentFilter, RECEIVER_EXPORTED)

        lastSuggestedNetwork?.let {
            val status = wifiManager.removeNetworkSuggestions(listOf(it))
            Log.i("WifiNetworkSuggestion", "Removing Network suggestions status is $status")
        }
        val suggestionsList = listOf(wifiNetworkSuggestion)

        var status = wifiManager.addNetworkSuggestions(suggestionsList)
        Log.i("WifiNetworkSuggestion", "Adding Network suggestions status is $status")
        if (status == WifiManager.STATUS_NETWORK_SUGGESTIONS_ERROR_ADD_DUPLICATE) {
            Log.d("es.paytef","Suggestion Update Needed")
            status = wifiManager.removeNetworkSuggestions(suggestionsList)
            Log.i("WifiNetworkSuggestion", "Removing Network suggestions status is $status")
            status = wifiManager.addNetworkSuggestions(suggestionsList)
        }
        if (status == WifiManager.STATUS_NETWORK_SUGGESTIONS_SUCCESS) {
            lastSuggestedNetwork = wifiNetworkSuggestion
            Log.d("es.paytef","Suggestion Added")
        }
    }
}
```

And regading my dependencies:
`
build.gradle(app)

```
    implementation("androidx.core:core-ktx:1.9.0")
    implementation("androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-ktx:2.6.2")
    implementation("androidx.activity:activity-compose:1.7.2")
    implementation(platform("androidx.compose:compose-bom:2023.03.00"))
    implementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui")
    implementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui-graphics")
    implementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling-preview")
    implementation("androidx.compose.material3:material3")
    testImplementation("junit:junit:4.13.2")
    androidTestImplementation("androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.5")
    androidTestImplementation("androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.1")
    androidTestImplementation(platform("androidx.compose:compose-bom:2023.03.00"))
    androidTestImplementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui-test-junit4")
    debugImplementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling")
    debugImplementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui-test-manifest")
```

I identify there some related issue with the ClassNotFoundException, when the device is lower than the API level of the class, as it's my case, but I need run the app on API level 27, so do you know some replacement to WifiNetworkSuggestion, or some workaround on similar issue.